# delayed ActionMailer fails to deliver multiple recipients

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, sidekiq

I have an mailer class like this

```
class Mailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def newsletter_scheduler()
    recipients = User.all.to_a
    Mailer.delay_for(certain_time.days).newsletter(recipients)
  end

  def newsletter(recipients)
    recipients.each do |user|
      Logger.log("sending newsletter to #{user.email}"
      mail(
        to: user.email,
        subject: "What's hot last week",
      ).deliver
  end
end
```

I'm not looking for alternative to implement this...
the problem is that this sends the newsletter to the last recipient only and multiple times
So for example in the `specs`

```
it 'sends newsletter to all users' do
  Mailer.newsletter_scheduler()
  newsletters = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries

  newsletters.each { |nl| p nl.to }
end
```

i get this (note: I have 5 users)

```
["josh@haley.org"]
["josh@haley.org"]
["josh@haley.org"]
["josh@haley.org"]
["josh@haley.org"]
```

can anybody tell me why this is happening while the logger showing the following

```
sending newsletter to gertrude@gleasonlittle.biz
sending newsletter to bell@cormier.org
sending newsletter to alexa_sanford@rosenbaum.name
sending newsletter to hillard@mcclure.org
sending newsletter to josh@haley.org
```

**[EDIT]** the following code have the same effect as the code above

```
class Newsletter
  def self.schedule
    recipients = User.all.map { |u| u.id }
    Mailer.delay_for(certain_time.days).newsletter(recipients)
  end
end

class Mailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def newsletter(recipients)
    recipients.each do |id|
      user = User.find(id)
      Logger.log("sending newsletter to #{user.email}"
      mail(
        to: user.email,
        subject: "What's hot last week",
      )
  end
end

Newsletter.schedule() #produces the same results in the specs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code also present another issue. `#deliver` is expected to be called outside the mail action as I shown you in my code above.

Consider to split your code

```
class NewsletterScheduler
  def self.execute
    User.all.each do |user|
      Mailer.delay_for(certain_time.days).newsletter(user)
    end
  end
end

class Mailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def newsletter(user)
    Logger.log("sending newsletter to #{user.email}"
    mail(to: user.email, subject: "What's hot last week")
  end
end

NewsletterScheduler.execute
```

---

Important warning: You should never pass complex object as arguments to a queue. Instead, always pass a reference.

In your case change

```
def newsletter(recipients)
```

to accepts an array of IDs instead of an array of User objects. The reason is that objects are complicated and internal state can change, especially if they are stored in a database. Moreover, serializing a primitive value is more efficient than serializing a complex object.

```
class NewsletterScheduler
  def self.execute
    User.all.each do |user|
      Mailer.delay_for(certain_time.days).newsletter(user_id)
    end
  end
end

class Mailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def newsletter(user_id)
    user = User.find(user_id)
    Logger.log("sending newsletter to #{user.email}"
    mail(to: user.email, subject: "What's hot last week")
  end
end
```

Comment: this doesn't work... without deliver in the no emails is sent... and with the deliver the same behaviour described above happens.

Comment: It can't have the same behavior if you correctly extracted the code as I shown. Please gist your updated code somewhere or update the existing answer.

Comment: You're still invoking `mail` multiple times inside the mailer. The loop must be moved outside as I shown in the `self.schedule`.

Comment: ok, there is a problem
`Mailer.delay_for(certain_time.days).newsletter(user_id).deliver` returns an error `undefined method 'deliver' for "ce123ffbd5b6cabc8a2c1f83":String` but
`Mailer.newsletter(user_id).deliver` works fine ?!

Comment: It looks like `.deliver` is not required. See https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Delayed-Extensions

Comment: yeah i found that out by trial and error... thanks for your help... i hereby to grant you an extra 25 :D